# How to grab a PHP variable using AJAX and JSON from one page to another?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here. I have been looking into this quite a while now. I have basically looked trough everything on google and on this page and still haven't understood how my first page should look like in order to get this to work.

```
<script>
//firstpage.php

function fetch(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'secondpage.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
         id:'ok'
      },
      success: function(data){
         //var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         if (data.phpvar == 'ok'){
            alert('Success!');// for testing
         }else{
            alert('Failure!');// for testing
         }
      }
   });
}
</script>
```

ajax requesting the second page:

```
<?php
//secondpage.php

if($_POST['id'] == 'ok'){
    $return_data['phpvar'] = 'ok';
    return json_encode($return_data);
}
?>
```

What am i doing wrong??? I'm new to ajax, so please explain the best way possible. My goal is simple enough, it is to grab PHP variable with value "ok" from the second page and pass it back to the first page as a type of a confirmation to find out which PHP if() condition was entered->(depends on the sql database response).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` and use `data` directly. jQuery usually detects JSON and automatically parses it. Add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax arguments to be sure though.

Besides that you should change your PHP script to *always* return *some* JSON - and if it's just an empty object.

Comment: Ok, so how would the whole script look like? Because nothing I do actually works.. Is there a way to grab a PHP variable from one page to another using a simple POST forward and back method with ajax or isn't there? Because if there is, then why don't I see a single workable example anywhere, not on stackoverflow, nor google? An actual example would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind!
My experience now with ajax has been that I don't really need to grab a PHP variable at any point. Because if something needs to be checked for existence, then we either use SESSION check or a COOKIE check on the 1st or the 2nd page. Otherwise we use jquery data to send it like so:

```
<script>
//firstpage.php

$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'secondpage.php',
   data:'id=ok&do=check',
   success:function(data){
   if(data=='good'){
      //do stuff
   }
   if(data=='bad'){
      //do stuff
   }
}});
</script>
```

requesting page:

```
if($_POST['id'] == 'ok' AND $_POST['do'] != ''){//something was sent, do..
    echo 'good';
}else    
if($_POST['id'] == 'ok' AND $_POST['do'] == ''){//if nothing was sent, do..
    echo 'bad';
}else{/*do nothing*/}
?>
```

And in the end if absolutely necessary, we can always try to find a way to run PHP in JS file and try to do a splitting of the data using PHP functions and then returning the split data as an ARRAY and then we can use array sections like $data[1] or $data[2].. etc.. in our code to perform different tasks using the exactly same data string in jQuery.